# Hi I need to change a value XML node before importing with all import

Tags: wordpress, wpallimport

Hi I have an XML file that contains several nodes with values of yes or no and wants to import them with WP all import

Such as:
fireplace: yes
Air-conditioning: yes
Heating: no

I want these to change with the slugs that I use.
Example:
if Fireplace: yes then give "tzaki" if no give nothing

If air-conditioning: yes then give "aircond" if no nothing

Can you please help me with the function editor?

Answer (score 0):

Look how to build your own functions:
https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/inline-php/

This must be entered in the field

```
[change_value({YOURIMPORTFIELD[1]})]
```

Put this in your Function Editor or Functions.php:

```
/********* Change Value of Fields *********/
function change_value( $content ) {
    if ($content == "fireplace: yes") {
        $converted = "tzaki";
        return $converted;
    } elseif ($content == "fireplace: no") {
        $converted = "";
        return $converted;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```